How to unlock the bootloader of HTC One A9?
I forgot my password so it got formated, I was gonna just set the phone again but the thing is my phones WiFi does not work (Maybe because of the firmware). So I thouht I could use Mobile Data but I need to set the APN and the Tools button is grayed out, so I can not do that (Is there a way?).
So I think the only way I might have is to re-flash its stock OS. And I started trying that.
But.. when I try to flash the ZIP RUU i downloaded from XDA Forums
using the flashing tool they provide (I tried others but got the same output) i get this error when the second zip is being written
(bootloader) ERR Update zip file failed.
(bootloader) ERR ZIP ERROR, exit read zip loop
(bootloader) ERR ZIP signature checking failed...
(bootloader) Update zip file OK
(bootloader) ERR ZIP ERROR CODE, 22
(bootloader) end@Done

I looked in Google and found that this maybe because the download is corrupted so i downloaded again but i got the same. Then I tried to flash the firmware because maybe it could be that but I get that same error. So as i looked more i thougt maybe is was because my bootloader is locked so looked in how to do that and followed the instructions in HTCDev for my specific model but the fastboot.exe file i got opens a terminal window but closes in a second so I did it using the Open PowerShell from here method but then instead of the response i should get as the instructions said i got this error
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] : /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/frp
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] Last Byte is 0X00, disable unlock
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] oem unlock Turn Off!

I looked for this in Google and a forum comment says it might be like a protection because of the reset, What can I do about this if I need to get my phone working again somehow?

The message mess that you first need a running Android OS, and there enable the OEM unlock settings entry in the developer settings. For flashing a firmware in locked state there is only the way to boot into recovery and then use the adb sideload way. Fastboot only works after unlocking the bootloader on your device.

@Robert Do I need TWRP custom recovery installed, because I do not have that installed.

Stock recovery ROM should also allow side loading, otherwise I wouldn't have mentioned it because you can not install nor boot a custom recovery with a locked bootloader.
